# Inserting rich text box value in database with format

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert rich text box  value in database with given format.Now value in rich text box is inserted and alignment get messy while inserting.In my rich text box I typed heading in bold but in my database I saved into normal text. I used varchar data type for this field.
I want to know how to store rich text box value with format

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set that column Collation as utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

You should use `text` data type for this field.